# Tabulating association frequency counts

Tags: r, dataset, data-mining

I have data which is in this format:

```
User Item
1   A
1   B
1   C
1   D
2   A
2   C
2   E
```

What I want to get is a frequency count for each pair. Order is not important so I don't want to count the inverse. I want to end up with a result similar to this, where the frequency counts are partitioned by user.

```
Pair Frequency
AB  1
AC  2
AD  1
AE  1
BC  1
BD  1
BE  0
CD  1
CE  1
```

What tool can I use to formulate this kind of table? I'd prefer some open source solution if possible.

**Edit- Added example for my comment below**

I'm reading in data from a CSV file using the following two lines and removing the factors with these two steps in code.

```
xa<-read.csv("C:/Direcotry/MyData.csv")
xa<-data.frame(lapply(xa, as.character), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

     User   Item
1  394324 Item A
2  124209 Item B
3  212457 Item C
4  427052 Item A
5  118281 Item D
6  156831 Item A
7  212442 Item E
8  156831 Item B
9  212442 Item A
10 177734 Item C
```

When I try running suggested answer, I get an error with this result:

```
Error in combn(x, 2) : n < m
```

Comment: There is no `x` defined in your sample code, so it's no surprise you're getting an error trying to compute `combn(x,2)`!

Answer (score 4):

Well R is open source.

Here's an example based on your tiny sample of data:

Here I just read your data in by copypasting it straight from your post:

```
> xa=read.table(stdin(),header=TRUE,as.is=TRUE)
0: User Item
1: 1   A
2: 1   B
3: 1   C
4: 1   D
5: 2   A
6: 2   C
7: 2   E
8:
```

So that's the data in. Then with a couple of lines of code:

```
> f=function(x) apply(combn(x,2),2,paste0,collapse="")
> table(unlist(tapply(xa$Item,xa$User,f)))

AB AC AD AE BC BD CD CE 
 1  2  1  1  1  1  1  1
```

If you need all the empty combinations explicitly as zeroes it takes another line or two (you need to generate all the possible combinations as a factor, rather than just the observed ones and tell `table` to include the empty ones).

Comment: So I tried your example and it works for your data perfectly. I try with my example, and I get the error I listed in my update. It says  error in combin. I can't figure out why, and I'm not that experienced in R to really understand what's causing it.

Comment: Ok so I solved the issue by first removing users which only have 1 item (not interested in these anyways). Can I ask a follow up if I wanted your result as a 3 column data frame? Ie. Term1, Term2, Count

Answer (score 0):

After some research and suggestions by Glen, I came up with the following code which gets me a 3 column CSV file with the pair combination plus frequency count. If anyone sees a better way, let me know! But this seems to work.

The errors I was referring to in my follow up comments were caused by users having purchased only at one location.

```
library(reshape2)

xa<-read.csv("C:/Input.csv",as.is=TRUE)

xa=xa[!duplicated(xa),]
xa<-data.table(xa)
setkey(xa,ContactId,PurchaseLocation)

tab=table(xa$ContactId)
xa=xa[xa$ContactId %in% names(tab[tab>1]),]

f=function(x) apply(combn(x,2),2,paste0,collapse="--")
xb<-as.data.frame(table(unlist(tapply(xa$PurchaseLocation,xa$ContactId,f))))
xc=with(xb, cbind(Freq, colsplit(xb$Var1, pattern = "--", names = c('a', 'b'))))
xc=subset(xc,a!=b & a!="" & b!="" & Freq>1)

write.csv(xc,file="C:/Output.csv")
```

Edit- I made a small change to make it order independent by sorting the data table on a key.